# Loss of Precision Due To Implicit Casting When Passing Variable As Function Parameter

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

void print (uint8_t in) {
    std::cout << (unsigned int) in << '\n';
}

int main() {
    uint16_t num = 257;
    print(num);

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Outputs `1` due to the truncation of the eight bit:

`uint16_t            -> uint8_t`

`0000 0001 0000 0001 -> 0000 0001`

Is there any way to get the compiler to warn for the loss of precision when num is converted from `uint16_t` to `uint8_t`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: *Is there any way to get the compiler to warn ...?*. Mentioning what compiler you're using is key to getting a relevant answer, don't you think? For gcc/clang, `-Wconversion` will emit a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention the compiler you're using I'll have to guess.
In Visual Studio warning level 2 or higher has to be activated to get the warning C4244 "conversion from 'type1' to 'type2', possible loss of data".